# YearArchiveView.date_field is required. ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I open up the documentation to Django.
I try to use the (YearArchiveView) view. when I go through the URL index/2020/ I get this error( YearArchiveView.date_field is required. ) what I understand that I have to use the attribute that called date_field and I already use.
so, how can I fix that error?
also, I need to know how can I access on this URL by any link into another page?, like from index.html

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, Http404, render_to_response
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Article, User
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.dates import ArchiveIndexView, YearArchiveView
class ArticleYearArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    template_name = 'index/article_archive_year.html'
    date_field = "date"
    allow_future = True
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path("<int:year>/", views.YearArchiveView.as_view(), name="article_archive_year")
]
```

artcile_archive_year.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Archive year</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for date in date_list %}
        <li>{{ date|date }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly referencing your view object. 
Instead of:

```
urlpatterns = [path("<int:year>/", views.YearArchiveView.as_view(), name="article_archive_year")]
```

Try:

```
urlpatterns = [path("<int:year>/", views.ArticleYearArchiveView.as_view(), name="article_archive_year")]
```

Specifically, note the use of `views.ArticleYearArchiveView` instead of `views.YearArchiveView`.